# Convert Facebook decoded json to PHP array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following PHP code:

```
define('TOKEN_FILE', 'fb_page_accestoken.txt'); // dont need to change this
$fb = new Facebook(array( 
                  'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
                  'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
                  'cookie' => true,
));

$access_token = file_get_contents('fb_app_token.txt');

$response  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token;
$responsez = json_decode(file_get_contents($response ,true)); 
print_r($responsez);
```

When I use the above code I decode the JSON string and get the following:

```
stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [category] => Media/news/publishing [name] => PAGE ABC [access_token] => abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 [perms] => Array ( [0] => ADMINISTER [1] => EDIT_PROFILE [2] => CREATE_CONTENT [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT [4] => CREATE_ADS [5] => BASIC_ADMIN ) [id] => 35645645678735 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [category] => Entertainment website [name] => Page 123 [access_token] => abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 [perms] => Array ( [0] => ADMINISTER [1] => EDIT_PROFILE [2] => CREATE_CONTENT [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT [4] => CREATE_ADS [5] => BASIC_ADMIN ) [id] => 1364564569777454 )
```

How can I get the above into a PHP array? For example to be able to extract the `access_token` of page id `1364564569777454`.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/json_decode.  Note the second (optional) argument for json_decode.

Comment: `$responsez->data[0]->id` or `responsez['data']['0']['id']` when `$responsez = json_decode(file_get_contents($response), true)`

Comment: @DaveChen excellent it worked. Instead of having _data[0]_ would it be possible to have its absolute name rather than its relatgive e.g. data['XYZ']?

Comment: Do you mean this page name? `[name] => PAGE ABC` You'll want to do a loop, to return the array that has that specific attribute.

Comment: Instead of having _responsez['data']['0']['id']_ one would have _responsez['data']['XYZ']['id']_ i.e. 0 instead of XYZ - something static

Answer (score 2):

```
responsez = json_decode(file_get_contents($response), true);
```

The second param in **json_decode** allow convert returned object into associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arr = array();
 foreach($responsez->data as $obj){
      $arr[] = array("page_id"=>$obj->id,"access _token"=>$obj->access_token);         
 }
 print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having troubles with the accounts JSON and this worked better for me:

```
        $request = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/' . $this->userID . '/accounts'))->execute();
        $graphObject = json_decode($request->getRawResponse(), true);

        foreach ($graphObject['data'] as $page) { // array['data', 'paging']
            if ($page['id'] == $this->fbAppPageID) {
                $this->pageToken = $page['access_token'];
            }
        }
        return $this->pageToken;
```